# I'm learning Work-energy theorem, this question popped into my mind about Force applied and displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

I know a lot but I'm not sure, I'm guessing if 400 J of work done on a 800 Newton object, if I'm correct, 400 N to 800 N... that is 0.5 m displacement, so by $W = \Delta \ KE$ why do I get 200 J? I was wondering if anyone can actually help.

So, 400 N to 800 N, the 400 N is applied for 0.451 s, that acceleration is 4.905 $m/s^{2}$ so the equation for distance shows that its displacement is .5 meters... and thus final velocity is 2.212155 m/s.

Do I multiply 800 N to the 0.5 m to get 400 J? And the mass of the 800 N object which is 81.54943935 kg.

So my hammer with 400 J of KE applies that 400 N (400 J s = 400 N m) to a 800 N nail, 400 N applied for 0.451 s, do I multiply the end 800 N times 0.5 m to get the work/kinetic energy used to displace it or what?

Comment: Maybe you could first mention the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

"If have 400 Joules of Work, which is 400 N•m, so 400 N's applied to a 800 Newton box, 400N's moves it by .5 meters right?"

No.

The 400N force can act along any arbitrary distance. Assuming there's no friction or other opposing forces on the box, the box will gain 400*d joules of energy, where d is the distance in metres.

If the force acts through 1m, the box gains 400N*1m = 400J of energy. If the force acts through 0.5m, the box gains 400N*0.5m = 200J of energy. If the force acts through 10m, the box gains 400N*10m = 4000J of energy.

For a given force through a given distance, then energy gained by the box is the same regardless of its mass, an 8kg box or an 800kg box doesn't make a difference. The difference only comes in when calculating the velocity of the box using KE = $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

Question... why are you calling it an 800N (I assume you mean the weight mg, with g=10m/s^2) box instead of an 80kg box?

Comment: In my original question, I did it right...I was confused it changed it....also, I used 800 Newtons implying 81.54kg's.....

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not really how it works. If you give 400J on a 800N (i.e. approximately 80kg in mass) box by pushing it on a frictionless surface, it will accelerate to about $\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot400\rm{J}}{80\rm{kg}}}\approx3\frac{\rm{m}}{\rm{s}}$ and then keep going forever. It's only if you're talking about specifically lifting the box against the force of gravity that there is any simple relationship like that.

Also, your question is very unclear, especially in the later parts.

Comment: So, what? I use a hammer with 400Joules to 800 N nail right? shouldn't it move in .5 meters?

Comment: @IBT98, No that's not right.

Comment: I see, I did an error, can somebody explain to me what to do? I used to know a lot about this but now Im put off, what is the problem.

Comment: @IBT98, can you post the question exactly as it is written?

Comment: I was just saying the correct thing, I can't type it word for word, so here is what I know. 400J's => 400Newtons, zero impact, just applied 400N's thus we understand 400/800 =.5 but a better method is 400J's/800N's =.5 meters displacement, so 400N's*.5Meters (W=Fs) is 200 Joules, I was being dumb and was questioning how can 200J's move a 800 newton box, but its the energy transferred, so 400J's which can move 400N's displaced by 1 foot, is 400J's displaces 800N's by .5 that is 400J's used up right? 400N's to 800N's, 400J's of work over 800N's is .5 meter displacement.

Comment: I can't remember but is how it went I think, "400N's pushing an 800 Newton box, that would be .5 meters displacement...400N's times .5 Meters is 200 Joules, how can that move a 800Newtons"